# Mean calculation Error in spark with Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate meanvalue for profit.

Spark 2.4.4

DataFrame looks like:-

```
+----------------+----------------+-------------------+
|     Customer   |CustomerCount   |profit|
+----------------+----------------+-------------------+
|Customer_162    |               8| 0.28|
|Customer_2634   |               1|0.31|
|Customer_1482   |               8|0.28 |

+----------------+----------------+-------------------+


    Code:
   newdf.select("Customer","CustomerCount","profit")
      .agg(sum("profit")
        .alias("sum"),
        count("CustomerCount").alias("count"))
      .withColumn("Mean", round(col("sum") /  sum("count").over(),2))
      .show()


Current Output shows like
        +----------------+-----+----+
        |             sum|count|Mean|
        +----------------+-----+----+
```

but i am trying to get output like

```
+----------------+----------------+--------------+
|     Customer   |CustomerCount   |profit| Mean
+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|Customer_162    |               8| 0.28 |0.29
|Customer_2634   |               1|0.31  |0.29
|Customer_1482   |               8|0.28  |0.29
+----------------+----------------+--------+
```

Kind Regards

Comment: You are calculating a value, not the column, why are you adding it to the column?

Comment: how the mean 0.05 is calculated?

Comment: @smart_coder: Sorry it was typo error. corrected now.... it should be 0.29....

Comment: updated the answer, please check If this works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below code might helpful.

```
val df1=df.select(round(mean($"profit"),2).alias("mean"))

df.join(df1).show()

/*
+-------------+-------------+------+----+
|     Customer|CustomerCount|profit|mean|
+-------------+-------------+------+----+
| Customer_162|            8|  0.28|0.29|
|Customer_2634|            1|  0.31|0.29|
|Customer_1482|            8|  0.28|0.29|
+-------------+-------------+------+----+
*/
```

Comment: Just a note, that you may want to enable `spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled` as `true` as the join is a cartesian product.

Comment: If any performance issues, try the following options, 1.broadcast small dfs, 2.repartitioning